# Replace $'\374', $'\344' and more with appropriate umlauts

Tags: bash, debian, shell, ssh, locale

after 2 days of research, I must ask the pros over here.

I had set up a NFS-share on my first Debian server at home. I copied over a few files from a windows 11 machine and now all the umlauts are messed up. Now I'm searching for a way to search all affected files and replace the wrong characters with the right ones.

Here come the details.

I access the system by SSH and locale says:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

files look like this:

```
-rwxrwx---  1 someuser somegroup 309424046 Jul  5  2018 'Star Trek - Deep Space Nine - S07E23 - Extreme Ma'$'\337''nahmen - SDTV.mkv'
-rwxrwx---  1 someuser somegroup      1149 Jun  5  2021 'Star Trek - Deep Space Nine - S07E23 - Extreme Ma'$'\337''nahmen - SDTV.nfo'
-rwxrwx---  1 someuser somegroup     14468 Jul  9  2018 'Star Trek - Deep Space Nine - S07E23 - Extreme Ma'$'\337''nahmen - SDTV-thumb.jpg'
-rwxrwx---  1 someuser somegroup 328043411 Jul  5  2018 'Star Trek - Deep Space Nine - S07E24 - In den Wirren des Krieges - SDTV.mkv'
-rwxrwx---  1 someuser somegroup      1506 Jun  5  2021 'Star Trek - Deep Space Nine - S07E24 - In den Wirren des Krieges - SDTV.nfo'
-rwxrwx---  1 someuser somegroup     17538 Jul  9  2018 'Star Trek - Deep Space Nine - S07E24 - In den Wirren des Krieges - SDTV-thumb.jpg'
-rwxrwx---  1 someuser somegroup 703251173 Jul  5  2018 'Star Trek - Deep Space Nine - S07E25-E26 - Das, was Du zur'$'\374''ckl'$'\344''sst - SDTV.mkv'
-rwxrwx---  1 someuser somegroup      3089 Jun  5  2021 'Star Trek - Deep Space Nine - S07E25-E26 - Das, was Du zur'$'\374''ckl'$'\344''sst - SDTV.nfo'
-rwxrwx---  1 someuser somegroup     10441 Jul  9  2018 'Star Trek - Deep Space Nine - S07E25-E26 - Das, was Du zur'$'\374''ckl'$'\344''sst - SDTV-thumb.jpg'
```

If I am directly in one of the directories, the following command works as expected.

```
for x in *$'\374'*; do echo "$x" "${x//$'\374'/ü}"; done
```

The question is if there is a way to do this for all affected files and directories in a complete directory tree and if it is possible for all special characters at once.
Or someone has an even better idea how to solve this case.

I would prefer a solution with standard toolset since I want to learn how to work on systems that don't have other tools installed.

Comment: I don't ever encourage you to massively change the contents of the files, it is not a content issue but a presentation stack issue.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the **perl** `rename` command, it can easily replace octal character encodings to proper unicode (or any other character).  Better yet, perl has great unicode capabilities and can transliterate between latin1 (and other character sets) and unicode.

Note: perl `rename` is also known as `file-rename`, `perl-rename`, or `prename`. It is not to be confused with the `rename` utility from `util-linux` which has completely different and incompatible capabilities and command-line options.   Perl `rename` allows you to use any
arbitrarily complex perl code to rename files, but is most often used to do
simple `sed`-like `s/search/replace/` operations on filenames.

On Debian, it is in the `rename` package.

The following one-liner uses perl `rename` along with the [Unicode::Map8](https://metacpan.org/release/Unicode-Map8) module (packaged in debian as `libunicode-map8-perl`) to rename these latin1 encoded characters to their unicode utf-8 equivalents.

It fixes not only the ü and ä diacritics you asked for, but also the ß eszett...and any other characters that can be mapped to a proper utf8 form.

Use with caution: The only language I'm competent in is English, my high-school German classes were about 40 years ago, and my university Linguistics & Hindi courses were about 30 years ago. This works well AFAICT, but I am far from an expert.

```
$ rename -n 'BEGIN {
               use Unicode::Map8;
               our $l1_map = Unicode::Map8->new("latin1")
             };

             our $l1_map;
             $_ = $l1_map->tou($_)->utf8' Star\ Trek\ *
rename(Star Trek - Deep Space Nine - S07E23 - Extreme Manahmen - SDTV.mkv, Star Trek - Deep Space Nine - S07E23 - Extreme Maßnahmen - SDTV.mkv)
rename(Star Trek - Deep Space Nine - S07E23 - Extreme Manahmen - SDTV.nfo, Star Trek - Deep Space Nine - S07E23 - Extreme Maßnahmen - SDTV.nfo)
rename(Star Trek - Deep Space Nine - S07E23 - Extreme Manahmen - SDTV-thumb.jpg, Star Trek - Deep Space Nine - S07E23 - Extreme Maßnahmen - SDTV-thumb.jpg)
rename(Star Trek - Deep Space Nine - S07E25-E26 - Das, was Du zurcklsst - SDTV.mkv, Star Trek - Deep Space Nine - S07E25-E26 - Das, was Du zurücklässt - SDTV.mkv)
rename(Star Trek - Deep Space Nine - S07E25-E26 - Das, was Du zurcklsst - SDTV.nfo, Star Trek - Deep Space Nine - S07E25-E26 - Das, was Du zurücklässt - SDTV.nfo)
rename(Star Trek - Deep Space Nine - S07E25-E26 - Das, was Du zurcklsst - SDTV-thumb.jpg, Star Trek - Deep Space Nine - S07E25-E26 - Das, was Du zurücklässt - SDTV-thumb.jpg)
```

Note that the `-n` option makes it a dry run, so it will only show what it
would do without actually renaming any files. Remove the `-n`, or replace it
with `-v` for verbose output, when you've confirmed that it does what you
want.

To use this recursively with a subdirectory tree, combine it with `find`. For example:

```
find /path/to/directory -type f -print0 |
  rename -n -0 '
     BEGIN {
       use Unicode::Map8;
       our $l1_map = Unicode::Map8->new("latin1")
     };

     our $l1_map;
     $_ = $l1_map->tou($_)->utf8'
```

---

BTW, for testing purposes, I converted your `ls -l` directory list into a script to create dummy files for rename:

```
touch 'Star Trek - Deep Space Nine - S07E23 - Extreme Ma'$'\337''nahmen - SDTV.mkv'
touch 'Star Trek - Deep Space Nine - S07E23 - Extreme Ma'$'\337''nahmen - SDTV.nfo'
touch 'Star Trek - Deep Space Nine - S07E23 - Extreme Ma'$'\337''nahmen - SDTV-thumb.jpg'
touch 'Star Trek - Deep Space Nine - S07E24 - In den Wirren des Krieges - SDTV.mkv'
touch 'Star Trek - Deep Space Nine - S07E24 - In den Wirren des Krieges - SDTV.nfo'
touch 'Star Trek - Deep Space Nine - S07E24 - In den Wirren des Krieges - SDTV-thumb.jpg'
touch 'Star Trek - Deep Space Nine - S07E25-E26 - Das, was Du zur'$'\374''ckl'$'\344''sst - SDTV.mkv'
touch 'Star Trek - Deep Space Nine - S07E25-E26 - Das, was Du zur'$'\374''ckl'$'\344''sst - SDTV.nfo'
touch 'Star Trek - Deep Space Nine - S07E25-E26 - Das, was Du zur'$'\374''ckl'$'\344''sst - SDTV-thumb.jpg'
```

Comment: Very concise answer, thank you. Is it also possible to rename corrupted folder names (beforehand)?

Comment: Just replace "-type f" with "-type d" to rename directories instead of filenames.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you cas and Thibault LE PAUL for your answers.

@Thibault LE PAUL I am not sure if it is only a presentation stack issue. After copying the files from Windows via NFS, even in Windows Explorer they were no longer displayed at all. Every file without umlauts was there. All files with umlauts were hidden. So I could not even copy the files back and try it over samba.

@cas I think your solution would work well. In the end I decided to give my own script a try. Mainly because there is no version of rename installed on my system and I wanted to do it with what I have at hand.

Here is my solution. It still contains an error if two special characters directly follow each other.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Variable declaration & initialization
rootDir="/srv/data"
#rootDir="/tmp/test"
echo "Initialized variable rootDir with value $rootDir."
treeDepth=$(find $rootDir -type d | awk -F"/" 'NF > max {max = NF} END {print max}')
echo "Initialized variable treeDepth with value $treeDepth."
dirArray=()
fileArray=()

# Function declaration
grep-invalid-utf8 () {
    perl -l -ne '/^([\000-\177]|[\300-\337][\200-\277]|[\340-\357][\200-\277]{2}|[\360-\367][\200-\277]{3}|[\370-\373][\200-\277]{4}|[\374-\375][\200-\277]{5})*$/ or print';
}

echo "Changing directory to $rootDir."
cd $rootDir
echo "Working directory is now $(pwd)."

echo "Looping over directory tree and doing renames as needed."
for ((i=1; i<=$treeDepth; i++)); do
    echo "Searching on level $i.";
    mapfile -t dirArray < <(find . -mindepth $i -maxdepth $i -type d | grep-invalid-utf8);

    for x in "${dirArray[@]}"; do
        firstPart="$(dirname "$x")"
        lastPart="/$(basename "$x")"

        echo "Renaming '$firstPart$(echo $lastPart | sed -e 's/'\''/'\''\\'\'\''/g')' to '$firstPart$(echo $lastPart | sed -e 's/'\''/'\''\\'\'\''/g' | iconv -f WINDOWS-1252 -t UTF-8)'";
        eval "$(echo "mv '$firstPart$(echo $lastPart | sed -e 's/'\''/'\''\\'\'\''/g')' '$firstPart$(echo $lastPart | sed -e 's/'\''/'\''\\'\'\''/g' | iconv -f WINDOWS-1252 -t UTF-8)'")";
    done
done

echo "Searching for files that need renaming."
mapfile -t fileArray < <(find . -type f | grep-invalid-utf8);

for x in "${fileArray[@]}"; do
    firstPart="$(dirname "$x")"
    lastPart="/$(basename "$x")"

    echo "Renaming '$firstPart$(echo $lastPart | sed -e 's/'\''/'\''\\'\'\''/g')' to '$firstPart$(echo $lastPart | sed -e 's/'\''/'\''\\'\'\''/g' | iconv -f WINDOWS-1252 -t UTF-8)'";
    eval "$(echo "mv '$firstPart$(echo $lastPart | sed -e 's/'\''/'\''\\'\'\''/g')' '$firstPart$(echo $lastPart | sed -e 's/'\''/'\''\\'\'\''/g' | iconv -f WINDOWS-1252 -t UTF-8)'")";
done
```

Best regards

Sascha